# How to install latest version of Apache Impala on AWS EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, impala, cloudera-cdh

how can I install Impala on AWS EMR ? Is there any way to install Impala on AWS? Is there any bootstrap script which can install latest version of Impala on AWS EMR?